# Error while fitting Pareto type 2 distribution

Tags: r, estimators, pareto-distribution

I am trying to fit a pareto type 2 distribution using the following code:

```
pareto2_distn <- fitdist(data, "pareto2", 
                         start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1))
```

But while trying to fit pareto type 2 distribution, I am getting the following warnings.

`Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(diag(varcovar)) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(1/diag(V)) : NaNs produced
3: In cov2cor(varcovar) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful`

And even when I check the estimates, I am getting NaN for the standard Error of estimate.

> `Fitting of the distribution ' pareto2 ' by maximum likelihood 
>   Parameters:
>             estimate Std. Error
>   shape 6.188671e+00 0.01389188
>   scale 3.275978e+05        NaN`

I cannot share the data which I have used for fitting the above distribution, I also tried providing a "reproducible example" but I am not able to produce one with the above mentioned error.

It would be helpful if anyone can tell me why am I getting this warning and how will this impact the output I am getting or provide some reading material for the same.

Comment: I guess that you should rescale you data in order to avoid numerical problems. You could also use a function specially devoted to the ML estimation of this distribution a.k.a. Lomax distribution. Try `flomax` in the (CRAN) `Renext`  R package.